# The term for the text between the opening and the closing tag?

Tags: html, xml, terminology

In `<span>foo</span>` what's the proper term to refer to `foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [W3C XML Specification:](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags)

> Definition: The text between the
>   start-tag and end-tag is called the
>   element's **content**

Comment: True, but it should be borne in mind that an element's content can also be different things than only text (see *Content of Elements* in the paragraph below the quoted part of the spec).

Answer (score 3):

The content of the text child node of the `<span>` element.

See [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html) on this:

> So if you do
>
> `<P>This is a paragraph</P>`
>
> you have created two nodes: an element P and a text node with content 'This is a paragraph'. The text node is inside the element, so it is considered a child node of the element.

Comment: "The text node with content"... Does this presuppose that the text node isn't the content, and the content is...the content?

Comment: @Jamie Dixon - It means that a text node can be empty. If it isn't empty, it has content.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I call it **content** or text

> The content in the span is foo

This sounds correct IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from w3schools

```
An XML element is everything from (including) the element's start tag to 
(including) the element's end tag.    
An element can contain other elements, simple text or a mixture of both.
Elements can also have attributes.

<bookstore>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore> 

In the example above, <bookstore> and <book> have element 
contents, because they contain other elements. <author> has 
text content because it contains text.
```

So, "text content"

Comment: w3schools have way too many errors and inaccuracies to be considered an authority on anything...

Comment: @Oded - But that doesn't mean they're always wrong; and in this case, I don't see any issues with their terminology... I'd say that the term "text content" for an XML/HTML element is pretty universally understandable

Comment: @Robert Harvey - Well... guess they got lucky ;)

Comment: @Oded: Provide a better source if you have one.

Comment: Although text content is more accurate than merely content... content could be another xml/html element, or cdata. specifying "text content" clearly differentiates from these.

Comment: @Oded: Ah, http://www.w3.org/. I always thought that w3schools was affiliated due to the similarity of name, but it appears this is not the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refer to it either as "content" or "text".

Given HTML as a markup language, you could also refer to it as "the described".

Answer (score 0):

Depends on context, to me.

In Javascript it would be the `innerHTML` property.

In HTML it is simply content:

- `<span>` is the start *tag*
- `foo` is *content*
- `</span>` is the end *tag*